# WinRT UDP communication exception during reading

Tags: c#, udp, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8

I'm working on a WP8 project which should transfer data via UDP to a connected app (WP8 also). I've decided to use the DatagramSocket to be able to share code with Windows 8.

The server and client app can connect to each other. After the client connected to the server it sends a command which should answer the server accordingly. The client connect and command sending code looks as follows:

```
var stream = await _udpSocket.GetOutputStreamAsync(server, UdpCommunication.Port);
var writer = new DataWriter(stream);
writer.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;

uint messageSize = writer.MeasureString(UdpCommunication.ReceiveImageCommand);
writer.WriteUInt32(messageSize);
await writer.StoreAsync();

writer.WriteString(UdpCommunication.ReceiveImageCommand);
await writer.StoreAsync();
await writer.FlushAsync();
```

So I'll transfer the message size and then the string command name. So far so good.

The server receives the MessageReceived event from the DatagramSocket and I get the DataReader and trz to read 4 bztes. During calling this I get the following exception message: 
"The operation identifier is not valid." (hresult -2147020579)

The code for the MessageReceived event:

```
DataReader reader = args.GetDataReader();
reader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;

await reader.LoadAsync(4);
uint messageSize = reader.ReadUInt32();

await reader.LoadAsync(messageSize);
string message = reader.ReadString(messageSize);
```

Does anybody have a clue why this exception is getting thrown and how to fix it? I've done TCP, Bluetooth and NFC and all are working and have similar code. But UDP gets me crazy...

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: I hate to be the barer of bad news, so just a comment.  But you are violating a sandbox restriction here.  Processes are not allowed to communicate with each other.  Local loopback is a typical malware technique.  You can disable it temporarily for testing purposes only but you can't get it through the store.  This is bound to blow a giant hole in your plan, sorry.

Comment: The communication happens between two devices. So your point shouldn't apply on my case but is good to know.

Answer (score 2):

You should not call `LoadAsync` on the `DataReader` returned from the `DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs.GetDataReader()` call. It seems that datagram is already loaded there. If you'd check `UnconsumedBufferLength` of that reader, you'll see it contains the full size of your datagram.

Actually, this make sense for UDP sockets, because in WinSock library (which, I guess, is the underlying implementation of WinRT sockets) you always receive the whole datagram in one `recvfrom` call (if you've provided big enough buffer for it, but I hope WinRT handles this for us). There's no need to read stream asynchronously - all your data is already there.

Therefore, just go ahead read your values from that stream. Your code would translate into something like:

```
DataReader reader = args.GetDataReader();
reader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
uint messageSize = reader.ReadUInt32();
string message = reader.ReadString(messageSize);
```

Comment: If this answer has solved your problem, please consider accepting it, so that other people reading this will benefit from this knowledge as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the above code doesn't work although you provided the correct answer along with the code. Here's how you get it to work:

```
var reader = args.GetDataReader();
reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
var size = reader.UnconsumedBufferLength;
var message = reader.ReadString(size);
```

Comment: They didn't explain it properly, but the scheme they are using is to pass the first 4-bytes as a header. These 4-bytes translate into a uint32, which is the message size for the subsequent string. The reason they do this is because there is no method in DataReader to read strings of unknown size. The LoadAsync will just hang waiting for data that might never come.